# What does this lvcreate call do?

Tags: linux, lvm

Could someone explain this line:

```
lvcreate -l 128 vg_appli -n lv_cmp
```

I think 128 is the size, but what is it doing as a whole?

Comment: Please read the docs (google, man page, or even `lvcreate --help`) before posting.

Answer (score 1):

`-l` designates the number of logical extents. From `man lvcreate`:

> -l, --extents LogicalExtentsNumber[%{VG|PVS|FREE|ORIGIN}]
>
> > Gives  the number of logical extents to allocate for the new logical volume.  The number can also be expressed as a percentage of the total space in the Volume Group with the suffix %VG, as a percentage of the remaining free space in the Volume Group with the suffix %FREE, as a percentage of the remaining free space for the specified PhysicalVolume(s) with the suffix %PVS, or (for a snapshot) as a percentage of the total space in the Origin Logical Volume with the suffix %ORIGIN.